# Are these all Higher Order Components?

Tags: reactjs

The definition of a HOC or a Higher Order Component is as follow:

> A higher-order component is a function that takes a component and
>   returns a new component.

An example for this is something like this:

```
const EnhancedComponent = higherOrderComponent(WrappedComponent);
```

But what about the following example?
Is in the following example **Masonry** component also a HOC?

```
<Masonry>
    {childElements}
</Masonry>
```

And what about this? is **ErrorBoundary** a HOC?

```
<ErrorBoundary>
    <MyComponent />
</ErrorBoundary>
```

Comment: The second one is not a HOC. It's only a component that renders the `children` prop.

Comment: The difference is that a HOC takes a component where as your second example is wrapping a React Element (i.e. the result of React.createElement). A HOC as described in your definition must take a component.

Comment: Thanks for your answers guys. I just extended my question (sorry for that). What about the third example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It helps if you can think about the types that are produced from the function (the HOC) and the JSX.

When you use JSX you're calling `React.createElement` which gives a new React Element.

This React Element is what is passed to your `Masonry` or `ErrorBoundary` as `children`.

Because the type is a React Element, it doesn't qualify for our definition of a HOC which must receive a *Component* and not an *Element*.

Your `higherOrderComponent` function, on the other hand, does take the `WrappedComponent` Component, and returns a new Component.

**Functions**

Another way to think about this is with simple functions. If I have a function that takes a function as its parameter, I can say that my function is a Higher-Order function.

Example:

```js
const filter = predicate => arr => arr.filter(predicate);
const lessThan10 = filter(x => x < 10);
const set1 = lessThan10([2, 4, 6, 8, 10]); // [2, 4, 6, 8]
const set2 = lessThan10([5, 10, 15, 20]);  // [5]
```

Here we can say that `filter` is a Higher-Order function because it takes a function as its parameter and it also returns a function as its result (a function waiting for an array).

We can also see that `lessThan10` is not a Higher-Order function. It neither takes a function as its parameter, nor does it return a function as its result.

Comment: One last question please. You said that: Your higherOrderComponent function, on the other hand, does take the WrappedComponent Component, and returns a new Component.
In this example, is the higherOrderComponent a HOC function, which returns a HOC component called EnhancedComponent? Is EnhancedComponent a Higher Order Component?

Comment: The term "Higher-Order Component" is referring to a specific type of Higher Order function. That is, a HOC is a function that takes a Component and returns a Component. The Component that is returned is not Higher-Order (it doesn't take or return any components).

Our `EnhancedComponent` is just a Component like any other.

Comment: The terminology is confusing because Higher-Order Components aren't actually Components at all, but functions that take and return Components.

Comment: Now I got it. Thanks a lot guys. I love you all.